# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'path' Модуль os не имеет атрибута path

Tags: python, pyinstaller

При компеляции простого hello world скрипта на питоне с помощью модуля pyinstaller.Прописал в командной строке pyinstaller -F имя.py.Все бы ничего но при компеляции увидел лишние предложения:

```
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'path 
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site.py", line 589, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = removeduppaths()
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site.py", line 127, in removeduppaths
    dir, dircase = makepath(dir)
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site.py", line 92, in makepath
    dir = os.path.join(*paths)'
```

В конце пишет:

```
54824 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

В папке вижу что все скомпилировалось корректно, но EXE файл который скомпилировался не открывается!
Почему???? помогите люди!

Comment: Потому что не нужно называть собственные скрипты как модули Python! Где-то у вас есть скрипт, с названием “os.py” - переименуйте его...

Comment: бляяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяя большое спаааааасиииииибоооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооо